# How to extract all 2nd level values (leaf nodes) from a 2-dimensional array and join with commas?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

How can I get the list of values from my array:

```
[data] => Array
        (
            [5] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 19
                    [1] => 18
                    [2] => 20
                )

            [6] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 28
                )

        )
```

Expected output result string will be: **19,18,20,28**

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried anything??

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With one line, no loop.

```
echo implode(',', call_user_func_array('array_merge', $data));
```

Try it [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fa2f9341cc99594cc40d47bde958a69cff98eb92).

Comment: Wouldn't this overwrite items that have the same index?

Comment: No. It will create new indexes.

Comment: @Rudi Added live example too.

Comment: this will only get the last of values that have the same string key (if say, all the inner arrays used the same string keys)

Comment: @fcrick OP dosen't have string keys. But you can combine this code with array_values to still get desired result.

Answer (score 4):

Use following php code:

```
$temp = array();
foreach($data as $k=>$v){
    if(is_array($v)){
        foreach($v as $key=>$value){
            $temp[] = $value;
        }
    }
}
echo implode(',',$temp);
```

Comment: Please include some explanation as to why you have designed your solution the way that you have.  Your answer differs from some of the others because it calls `is_array()`; perhaps you'd like to explain why this is a useful inclusion.  Also, I don't see any point in declaring `$k` and `$key` if you never use them.

Answer (score 0):

try with this..

```
foreach($data as $dataArr){
    foreach ($subArray as $value) {
        $res[] = $value;
    }
}
echo implode(',', $res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following code.

```
$string = '';
foreach($yourarray as $k){
  foreach($k as $l){
     $string. = $l.",";
  }
}
```

Comment: This is not clean because it generates an unwanted trailing comma on `$string`.  (your answer is also missing an explanation, all posts on SO should include some supporting text that explains how the method works and/or why it is an appropriate method for the question)

Answer (score 0):

Just loop over sub arrays. Store values to $result array and then [implode](http://php.net/implode) with ,

```
$result = array();
foreach ($data as $subArray) {
    foreach ($subArray as $value) {
        $result[] = $value;
    }
}
echo implode(',', $result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = array(5 => array(19,18,20), 6 => array(28));
foreach ($data as $array) {
    foreach ($array as $array1) {
        echo $array1.'<br>';
    }
}
```

Try this one. It will help you

Comment: This post: 1. Does not provide the desired output. 2. Does not provide any explanation (is a low-value / code-only answer)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't really taken the time to consider any fringe cases, but this is an unorthodox method that will directly provide the desired output string without loops or even generating a new, temporary array.  It's a tidy little one-liner with a bit of regex magic.  ([Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/k5asDf/1/))  It effectively removes all square & curly brackets and double-quoted keys with trailing colons.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7ee14d19f0750a2bf9a0833421e0f7d5d75464c2))

```
$data=[5=>[19,18,20],6=>[28]];
echo preg_replace('/[{}[\]]+|"\d+":/','',json_encode($data));
```

Output:

```
19,18,20,28
```

To be clear/honest, this is a bit of hacky solution, but I think it is good for SO researchers to see that there are often multiple ways to achieve any given outcome.

Answer (score 0):

Since all of the data that you wish to target are "leaf nodes", `array_walk_recursive()` is a handy function to call.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/006ba2cb40f8c88faafe2e4202c18505b704ff68))

```
$data=[5=>[19,18,20],6=>[28]];
array_walk_recursive($data,function($v){static $first; echo $first.$v; $first=',';});
```

Output:

```
19,18,20,28
```

This method uses a `static` declaration to avoid the implode call and just iterates the call of `echo` with preceding commas after the first iteration. (no temporary array generated)

Answer (score -2):

Just use nested foreach Statements

```
$values = array(); 
foreach($dataArray as $key => $subDataArray) {
   foreach($subDataArray as $value) {
       $values[] = $value;
   }
}
$valueString = implode(',', $values);
```

Edit: Added full solution..